# How do I filter based on a count within summarise in order to use as part of other summarise functions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to figure out how to filter after grouping my data within `summarise`.  I have 2 created columns below.  I'd ideally like to filter the `seasonTotal` column within summarise to a value of greater than 3, and then calculate the homeRunsPerSeason based on that filtered count.

Reprex below:

```r
library(Lahman)
library(tidyverse)

data <- Lahman::Batting

data <- data %>% 
  filter(yearID > 2015)

grouped_data <- data %>% 
  group_by(playerID) %>% 
  summarise(seasonTotal = n(),
            homeRunsPerSeason = sum(HR / seasonTotal)
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate each of the steps you want to accomplish. Calculate the season total, filter, then summarize.

```
grouped_data <- data %>% 
  group_by(playerID) %>% 
  mutate(seasonTotal = n()) %>% 
  filter(seasonTotal > 3) %>% 
  summarise(homeRunsPerSeason = sum(HR / seasonTotal))
```

Comment: What if I wanted to include seasonTotal as part of the final df?

Comment: Then you need to include in the the summarize. For example `summarize(..., seasonTotal=first(seasonTotal))`

Comment: I don't fully understand.  What does first do?